# How do I find out the size of the flash memory in the code itself?

Tags: stm32, hal

I want to get the limiting address of the flash in the code itself, or at least the size of this flash.

I found only the start address of the flash in the `stm32f302xc.h` file, but did not find the end address.

```
/** @addtogroup Peripheral_memory_map
  * @{
  */

#define FLASH_BASE            0x08000000UL /*!< FLASH base address in the alias region */
#define SRAM_BASE             0x20000000UL /*!< SRAM base address in the alias region */
#define PERIPH_BASE           0x40000000UL /*!< Peripheral base address in the alias region */
#define SRAM_BB_BASE          0x22000000UL /*!< SRAM base address in the bit-band region */
#define PERIPH_BB_BASE        0x42000000UL /*!< Peripheral base address in the bit-band region */
```

What defines are responsible for this, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you want is described in the reference manual [RM0366](https://www.st.com/resource/en/reference_manual/dm00094350-stm32f301x68-and-stm32f318x8-advanced-armbased-32bit-mcus-stmicroelectronics.pdf) in section ***29.2 Memory size data register***.

ST provide this functionaility but for some reason they don't always give an easy way to access it in the headers.

The address of this register is `FLASHSIZE_BASE`.  You have to read it at run-time, eg:

```
uint16_t flash_size_kb = *(const uint16_t*)FLASHSIZE_BASE;
```

Comment: Your variable name is misleading. kb =125 Byte, kiB=1024 Byte. So it should either be kiB or even better multiply it by 1024 and drop the _kb and use size_t. I prefer the latter as you more likely need the size in bytes in code than size in kiB.

Comment: Millions of engineers (including me) have been using kb to refer to 1024 bytes long before "kib" was thought of and will continue to do so long after "kib" is forgotten as a silly idea.  No one I have ever heard of uses kb to refer to 125 bytes.

Comment: I worked with many different eeprom, flash and sram chips and many of them do in fact use b to refer to bits and not bytes. Storage drives use power of 10, while RAM uses powers of 2. Those millions of engineers are all wrong

Comment: There is not a single RAM or ROM chip in existence where b means 125 bytes.  It does very regularly means 1024 bits which is 128 bytes.  Whole drives like USB drives or SD cards sometimes use 1000 not 1024, but whole drives are never labelled in bits, only megabytes or gigabytes or more.

Comment: True, but you are promoting inconsistency. Convention over truth. What you write means 125 byte, can be understood as 128 byte, but you really mean 1024 byte. Why not use size_t and avoid any confusion?

Comment: The type is fixed by the width of the register, I have no control over it.  As for truth, you can't just come along and try to change the meaning of kilobyte when it is long established and claim the new unit is the truth and what was already widely understood is not the truth.  You could say it is ambiguous, but to say it is not the truth is ridiculous.

Comment: Kilo is derived from the Greek word for thousand. It has always meant thousand. You are the one changing it by accepting a convention. Example:  how long does it take to write 10kb flash size at 10kbps? You'd think 1 second, but with your notation it is 8192 second. size_t always means size in bytes, kiB always means size in 1024 bytes. Although I would accept the convention of 1k without a b or B to mean 1024 bytes, but when you add the b or B you are using a notation that already has a different meaning. I've seen bugs in code because of this inconsistency. All my code uses proper units.

Comment: Different things mean different things to different people.  If you care that your code makes sense to ancient greeks, then good for you.  My code makes perfect sense to every competent software engineer.  This is demonstrated by the fact that it was upvoted and accepted as correct nearly a year before you even read it. You do not have enough reputation to vote so there is nothing you can do or say that anyone cares about.

Answer (score 2):

STM32 MCU families come in different flash sizes, that's why it's not defined in their header files. Although STM32CubeMX code generator could, in theory, add it when you select the exact model of your MCU. But this would mean code might not work if you flash it to variant with a different flash size.

However some STM32 MCUs come with a Flash size data register that contains information about the flash size. This address is often found in a header file and sometimes a macro is included. Note that it not a compile time constant, but a ROM constant that needs to be read at runtime.

stm32f3xx_hal_flash_ex.h contains the following register address:

```
#define FLASH_SIZE_DATA_REGISTER (0x1FFFF7CCU)
```

You can use it like this:

```
const size_t FLASH_SIZE = (*((uint16_t*)FLASH_SIZE_DATA_REGISTER)) << 10;
```

For the stm32g4xx there is a macro defined in stm32g4xx_hal_flash.h:

```
FLASH_SIZE
```

Be careful with writing your own macro for this as the flash size is not always linear with the value in the register. In the case of the stm32g4xx the value 0xFFFF means either 128kiB or 512kiB as seen below:

```
#define FLASH_SIZE_DATA_REGISTER        FLASHSIZE_BASE

#if defined (FLASH_OPTR_DBANK)
#define FLASH_SIZE                      ((((*((uint16_t *)FLASH_SIZE_DATA_REGISTER)) == 0xFFFFU)) ? (0x200UL << 10U) : \
                                        (((*((uint32_t *)FLASH_SIZE_DATA_REGISTER)) & 0xFFFFUL) << 10U))
#define FLASH_BANK_SIZE                 (FLASH_SIZE >> 1)
#define FLASH_PAGE_NB                   128U
#define FLASH_PAGE_SIZE_128_BITS        0x1000U /* 4 KB */
#else
#define FLASH_SIZE                      ((((*((uint16_t *)FLASH_SIZE_DATA_REGISTER)) == 0xFFFFU)) ? (0x80UL << 10U) : \
                                        (((*((uint32_t *)FLASH_SIZE_DATA_REGISTER)) & 0xFFFFUL) << 10U))
#define FLASH_BANK_SIZE                 (FLASH_SIZE)
#define FLASH_PAGE_NB                   ((FLASH_SIZE == 0x00080000U) ? 256U : 64U)
#endif
```

The same applies to flash page size. Page size depends on the family and sometimes on the flash size. Sometimes ST provides a macro for this too.